# Sending data through InfoWindow to another activity Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I have a for loop which populate markers on my map. The for loop also contains an `OnInfoWindowClickListener` so that an activity opens when clicking of the InfoWindow. This activity should display details depending on which InfoWindow is selected. Now the InfoWindow displays different details for different markers as it should but the activity which opens when clicking on the different InfoWindows is displaying the same information every time.

the for loop:

```
for (final infoToStore details : info) {
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(details.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(details.getLng())))
        .title(details.getName())
        .snippet(details.getDesc()));

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoWindow.class);
                intent.putExtra(NAME, details.getName());
                intent.putExtra(DESCRIPTION, details.getDesc());
                intent.putExtra(CATEGORY, details.getCat());
                intent.putExtra(IMAGE_URL, details.getUrl());
                intent.putExtra(PUSH_ID, details.getPushID());
                startActivity(intent);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoWindow.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

part of the code of the activity which opens when selecting an InfoWindow:

```
name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desc);
    cat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cat);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    report = (Button) findViewById(R.id.report);

    String nameString = returnValueFromBundles (MainActivity.NAME);
    String descString = returnValueFromBundles (MainActivity.DESCRIPTION);
    String catString = returnValueFromBundles (MainActivity.CATEGORY);
    String URLString = returnValueFromBundles (MainActivity.IMAGE_URL);
    final String pushID = returnValueFromBundles(MainActivity.PUSH_ID);

    name.setText(nameString);
    desc.setText(descString);
    cat.setText(catString);


    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(URLString)
            .into(image);

    report.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailTo","jolan.goburdhun@uom.umail.ac.mu",null));
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Reporting a service");
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, pushID);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an email client"));
        }
    });

}

private String returnValueFromBundles(String key) {
    Bundle inBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String returnedValue = inBundle.get(key).toString();
    return returnedValue;
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate startActivity calls, second one without extras.

Comment: Remove this call , startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoWindow.class));

Comment: I did that mistake because I got confused. But it still didn't solve the problem. d4h provided me with the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, You will get different value on `InfoWindow Click` if your bean (`details`) have different value.

```
 for (final infoToStore details : info) {
        marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(details.getLat()), Double.parseDouble(details.getLng())))
                .title(details.getName())
                .snippet(details.getDesc()));
         // Attach your bean with marker
        marker.setTag(details);

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                //Get Attached bean from marker
                infoToStore infoAttached = ((infoToStore) marker.getTag());

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoWindow.class);
                intent.putExtra(NAME, infoAttached.getName());
                intent.putExtra(DESCRIPTION, infoAttached.getDesc());
                intent.putExtra(CATEGORY, infoAttached.getCat());
                intent.putExtra(IMAGE_URL, infoAttached.getUrl());
                intent.putExtra(PUSH_ID, infoAttached.getPushID());
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First thing first - remove your `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` from `for` loop, there is no need to do that. Instead you can set it outside of the `for loop`

And your problem is -

```
startActivity(intent);
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoWindow.class));
```

Why are you starting activity twice time? just remove the second line and you are good to go ;-)

Comment: d4h provided me with the solution I was looking for below! thanks for helping anyway!